# Amazon MWS ListOrders Response

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am making my first steps with `Amazon MWS Api` `(PHP)`.

I just used the included Sample file modified with my Access-Data.
Actually it's working fine, however, I just get an unformatted string response instead of `XML`. Trying the same with `Amazon Scratchpad` I get an `XML` response.

Would be nice if somebody could point me in the right direction, thanks!
Marcel

```
echo ("Service Response\n");
echo ("=============================================================================\n");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
```

Comment: it is unclear from your question where `$response` comes from, whether it even needs the `toXML()` call and subsequently why loading it into a DOMDocument is failing. Please be more specific in what you are doing, what you tried and in what way it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Marcel replace last two lines with these and it should work, works for me.

```
$xml_data = $dom->saveXML();
$dom->loadXML($xml_data);
$orderArray = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
```